# I want to enter the text of selected checkboxes in labels inside a panel. CheckBoxes and the panel containing labels are in different forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, controls, panel

```
public void TestLoad()
{
    DeptTest dt3 = new DeptTest();
    foreach (CheckBox c in dt3.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        if(c.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (Label l in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                l.Text = c.Text;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function I've been trying to implement. The text attribute of labels isn't being affected.

Comment: This design doesn't seem . you can have a commnon Dictionary<checkboxstring,bool> and then set label text to those who has bool value to true.Initialize your dictionary with all the checkbox as string

Answer (score 0):

The code currently will set ALL label texts to the last checkbox in the list that is checked.

Are there specific labels for specific checkboxes? Or maybe a list of the checkbox values could be concatenated into a single label.

I recommend setting a breakpoint and watching the flow yourself. Stepping back and describing what you are trying to achieve might help.